# Merge common objects in array and add frequency

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array :

```
[
    {
        "id": "#1",
        "quantity": 2
    },
    {
        "id": "#2",
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "id": "#3",
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "id": "#1",
        "quantity": 2
    },
    {
        "id": "#2",
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "id": "#3",
        "quantity": 1
    }
]
```

I want the result to look like

```
[
    {
        "id": "#1",
        "quantity": 4
    },
    {
        "id": "#2",
        "quantity": 2
    },
    {
        "id": "#3",
        "quantity": 2
    }
]
```

Basically combine the objects with same ID, and add up the quantity.
I can do this using 2 for loops. But is there a more optimized way to solve this in Javascript?

Comment: If you go for an object with unique keys, it's a little easier -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/f91fL3ss/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will do the job:

```
function transform(a) {
    const seen = {};
    const ret = [];
    a.forEach(o => {
        const id = o.id;
        seen[id] = (seen[id] || 0) + o.quantity;
    });

    for (let key in seen) {
        ret.push({
            id: key,
            quantity: seen[key]
        });
    }
    return ret;
}
console.log(transform([{
    "id": "#1",
    "quantity": 2
}, {
    "id": "#2",
    "quantity": 1
}, {
    "id": "#3",
    "quantity": 1
}, {
    "id": "#1",
    "quantity": 2
}, {
    "id": "#2",
    "quantity": 1
}, {
    "id": "#3",
    "quantity": 1
}]));
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is firstly reduce the array to an object, and add quantity if the key is the same, and then get the object's value:

```js
var arr = [
    {
        "id": "#1",
        "quantity": 2
    },
    {
        "id": "#2",
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "id": "#3",
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "id": "#1",
        "quantity": 2
    },
    {
        "id": "#2",
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "id": "#3",
        "quantity": 1
    }
]

console.log(
  Object.values(arr.reduce((obj, rec) => {
    if(obj[rec.id] === undefined) {
      obj[rec.id] = rec;
    } else {
      obj[rec.id].quantity += rec.quantity;
    }
    return obj;
  }, {}))
)
```